# Word meaning 'to make subject of great attention'.

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a criticism of the media's coverage of the Charleston shooting, and that the fact that they give front page attention to the shooter, profiles of the shooter etc.

eg.

> While there may be a public interest in knowing that a mass shooting
>   has taken place and the nature of the attack, it is irresponsible for
>   the media to [something] the shooter by giving them front page
>   attention complete with photos, full names, and biographies.

***Martyr*** is similar to the word I'm looking for, in that a martyr becomes renouned, but of course the media coverage isn't persecution or a killing.

***Making a celebrity of*** also kind of expresses what I mean, but a *celebrity* doesn't really fit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's ***glorify***, but that implies *favourable* treatment by the media. So in practice the most common way to express this is to talk about *not giving them **the oxygen of publicity***.

Answer (score 2):

spotlight (verb) or highlight both have neutral connotations

Answer (score 1):

***aggrandize or aggrandise***

> verb (transitive)
>   to increase the prestige of someone. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aggrandize)

Comment: +1 For effort. But I'm not sure in this case they're giving the killer _prestige_ they're giving them _recognition_.

Comment: *lionize* has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Exalt](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exalt) may suggest an exagerated coverage of the person involved:

> - To increase the effect or intensity of; (AHD)

Answer (score -2):

**hound** (*verb*):

To [harass](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/harass), [persecute](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/persecute) or [pursue](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pursue) relentlessly *(one of these verbs may also be suitable?)*

> *She was hounded by the Italian press.*

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hound)

Comment: That's absolutely not what I'm looking for.